# Carousel dinámico de imagenes varias carpetas C#, Asp.Net core mvc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5, asp.net-core-mvc

Mostrar en carousel las imagenes que tengo en una carpeta, la ruta esta almacenada en mi DB en un campo llamado rutaCarpeta. Dentro del proyecto tengo creada la misma carpeta y es ahi donde esta el repertorio de imagenes. He realizado esto, pero veo que aun no logro hacer que me muestre las imagenes. Cada vez que yo seleccione un area debe de mostrar un carousel de imagenes distinto según la que seleccione. Claro en mi DB tengo las rutas y las carpetas creadas con sus imagenes para cada area dentro del proyecto.

Esta es la ruta en mi db "El imgEmpaque cambia segun cada area" el campo se llama rutaCarpeta dentro de mi tabla en la DB
\srvfileserver\IT-Desarrollos\Desarrollo-Guandy\PresentacionesPowerPoint\Presentaciones\wwwroot\imgEmpaque

```
    public IActionResult VerArea(int id)
    {
        var encuentraArea = context.PmAreasPresentacions.Find(id);//buscamos el area por ID

        if (encuentraArea == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

  
        var rutaCompleta = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", encuentraArea.RutaCarpeta);

   
        var imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(rutaCompleta).Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));

        var viewModel = new AreaViewModel
        {
            RutaCarpeta = encuentraArea.RutaCarpeta,
            Imagenes = imagenes.ToList()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Vista

```
<div id="carouselExampleAutoplaying" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @foreach (var imagen in Model.Imagenes)
        {
            <div class="carousel-item @(imagen == Model.Imagenes.First() ? "active" : "")">
                <img src="~/@Model.RutaCarpeta/@imagen" alt="Imagen de área">
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleAutoplaying" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleAutoplaying" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

*Al ejecutar la aplicacion no me muestra las imagenes, aparece el icono de imagen seguido de un texto "imagen de area" lo tengo en mi alt del SRC.

He realizado un debug en mi funcion y en el foreach de la vista para validar que es lo que me esta trayendo y si efectivamente recibo la ruta en la funcion y las imagenes que lleva, y en la vista recibo los nombres de esas imagenes pero no las muestra.

Alguna solucion?

Comment: Antes que te agarren a negativos, lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822, que no te sorprenda que tu pregunta tal cual está, termine cerrada, para evitar esto último, el contenido del link te dará ideas de lo que debería ir en la pregunta para obtener buenas chances de conseguir respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Suena a algo que le pedirías a ChatGPT... Cómo armar un carousel dinámico? Cargas el componente del carousel, cargas los url de la bd, a las imágenes le pones el src="urlImagen", y lo muestras. Listo. Espero sea de ayuda /s.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @Arriel he dado mas detalles de mi problema

Comment: Las url a tus imagenes deben ser iguales a las url de tu sitio.. estas seguro que se arman asi en tu codigo?? y tenes acceso a las imagenes???

Comment: @gbianchi si de hecho valido o abro dentro del proyecto la carpeta y es la misma ruta, en mi codigo cuando hago el debug veo que obtengo la misma que esta en la DB y me lee las imagenes que van dentro, si tengo acceso a las imagenes

Comment: tu ruta no debe ser fisica.. debe ser una url.. eso se entiende no??? porque insistes con que abris la carpeta, pero tu sitio necesita abrir una url para las imagenes...

Comment: Url? porque? No debo de abrir una Url, tengo las carpetas creadas en mi proyecto y la ruta de mi DB es lo que indico arriba

Comment: porque tu web se ejecuta del lado del cliente.. no en el servidor, y los archivos son servidos por el servidor al cliente... el cliente no conoce rutas fisicas, conoce urls... creo que deberias repasar el concepto de como funciona una web...

Comment: @gbianchi creo que me estas comprendiendo mal lo que deseo hacer, como se supone que leeré las carpetas, claramente necesito la ruta o el path en donde estan mis imagenes, ahí agregue mas detalles arriba, lee...
pero gracias por el dato!

Comment: No, vos no estas comprendiendo como funciona una pagina web, y un control image... las imagenes no se cargan desde tu pc, las imagenes tienen que estar en una ruta web. Como las guardaste en tu db, es tu problema, pero cuando llega al navegador tu pagina, este busca los src de los img y trae las imagenes desde ahi.. el navegador, no conoce tu disco, conoce el servidor que le dio la pagina, y conoce urls desde donde quiere leer las imagenes... me parece que no entendes como funciona la web, puede ser?

Comment: Ya he compredido mejor, ahora te pregunto, también tengo un campo llamado rutaImagen y porque ahí si me reconoce las imágenes y me las muestra junto con otros campos que tengo en mi DB, ya que estoy listandolos en mi Index?

Comment: desconozco porque ahi te funciona.. capaz ahi si tenes las url... no se de que me hablas...

Comment: @gbianchi  Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @gbianchi la url queda armada de esta forma, String
\\srvfileserver\IT-Desarrollos\Desarrollo-Guandy\PresentacionesPowerPoint\Presentaciones\wwwroot\imgEmpaque\1.png

Eso es lo que obtengo cuando realizo el debug en mi funcion.

Comment: y eso no es una url valida.. o si??? si la pegas directamente en tu navegador, obviamente no se ve la imagen... y de ahi, vienen todos tus problemas... cual es la url real a tus imagenes????

Comment: De hecho si la pego en el navegador si me abre la imagen, es lo que me confunde. Mis carpetas estan en wwwroot, cada carpeta tiene imagenes claramente, pero no entiendo, estoy confundido, entiendo que chrome no puede acceder al directorio como tal. Pero entonces que es lo que deberia hacer?

Comment: @gbianchi lo has visto?

Comment: TE lo abre, porque el navegador tiene acceso a tus discos, y te esta abriendo el link a tu disco.. IIS no tiene acceso a esa ruta.. como es la ruta de la pagina?? es localhost:xxxx/pagina... entonces, tus imagenes deberian estar en esa ruta... creo que esto mejor, lo vemos en el [chat], no entendes como funciona una web.. fijate donde estan las imagenes de esta web por ejemplo, o de cualquiera!

Comment: Creo que te encanta ofender a los usuarios que no saben, he corregido mi error. Todos empezamos de abajo y nadie nace sabiendo.  Gracias de igual forma por tus aportes.